# Creating multiple files in solution folder using T4 template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, t4, tangible-t4-editor

I am trying to create multiple files in an existing project within the Solution Folder using T4 template, based on [tangible T4 template](https://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/how-to-generate-multiple-output-files-from-a-single-t4-template.html). I followed the steps in the document but can't generate the multiple files with the structure below. There were no errors occurred during the process, so I am expecting that it will generate the files. I've included the codes here, please see below.

[image]

MultipleOutputFiles.tt

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude" #>
<#

var manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this);

#>

    // this output code will be written to MultipleOutputFiles.cs

<#
var fileProperties=new FileProperties();

manager.StartNewFile("Outputfile9.txt","SomeOtherProject","SubFolder", fileProperties);

#>

    // this output code will be written to Outputfile2.txt
<#

manager.Process();

#>
```

for TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude.tt complete code, you can get from this link [TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude.tt](https://github.com/renegadexx/T4.Helper/blob/master/Source/TemplateFilemanager.CS.ttinclude). Take note that there is an error using the `.First()` since there is no value in the collection yet, I changed it to `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: This link seems to be solving a similar goal by slightly different means. Maybe of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296544/write-t4-generated-code-to-separate-output-files